# Passing a state value React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to link the `backgroundColor` value in the `styles container` to the `state: color` so the background color will change to whatever color I put on the `textInput`. Here are my codes. Thank you!

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
    state = {
        color: '',
    };

    _color = (text) => {this.setState({color: text})};
    _applyAndClear = () => {
                            this.setState({color: ''})}

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput 
            style={styles.input}
            value = {this.state.color}
            onChangeText = {this._color}
            onSubmitEditing = {this._applyAndClear}
        />  
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'someColor',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  input: {
    borderWidth: 3,
    width: 100,
    height: 40,
    borderColor: 'white',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with the following:

```
<View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: this.state.color }]}>
```